# How to split a large data set based on value of particular variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working through an exercise in a textbook that is asking me to split my data set into two groups. The groups are based upon the ordered values of the `fitted` column. Which I arranged in ascending order using the `arrange()` function from the `Tidyverse` package. Observe the `rowid` are not in order anymore so I can't use that as a filtering option.

```
structure(list(rowid = c(24, 23, 28, 25, 35, 30, 39, 33, 40, 
31, 32, 7, 27, 11, 18), Total_Labour_hrs = c(4314, 4114, 4178, 
4289, 4016, 4226, 4146, 4475, 4555, 4121, 3998, 4110, 4347, 4401, 
4195), Cases_Shipped = c(248328, 227996, 245743, 249894, 252225, 
256506, 270051, 269121, 265239, 271854, 293225, 269334, 273848, 
269189, 293880), Labour_Hrs_Cost = c(8.5, 7.22, 8.12, 8.08, 7.85, 
7.79, 8.19, 8.01, 7.55, 7.89, 9.01, 7.23, 7.39, 7.05, 8.38), 
    Holiday = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    fitted = c(4233.43014593002, 4234.27973216581, 4236.39863043405, 
    4240.19244186657, 4245.05531064968, 4249.21476291559, 4254.60935901285, 
    4256.24725771141, 4259.24818049515, 4259.97827069745, 4262.05302404833, 
    4266.68440079867, 4268.13071857239, 4268.94015759698, 4270.8631537863
    ), residuals = c(80.5698540699768, -120.279732165811, -58.398630434046, 
    48.8075581334297, -229.055310649683, -23.2147629155879, -108.609359012852, 
    218.752742288589, 295.751819504853, -138.978270697446, -264.053024048329, 
    -156.684400798672, 78.869281427611, 132.05984240302, -75.863153786303
    )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

In particular the question requires me to split the data set in half based on the order of the `fitted` values. The real data set I'm working with is only 52 rows. So I can easily go to the 26th row, reference the value in the cell corresponding to the `fitted` variable and then use a logical argument such as `filter(.data = Grocery_Retailier_arranged_fitted, fitted <= value)` and split the data.

But since I'm working on my skills to use in more challenging environments and larger data sets I was wondering how would I go about this with a data set that has millions of rows? Sure I suppose I could go about it manually, but I envision this being a problem if say I needed to split the data into more smaller data sets.

What would be the best practices or methodology to go about this correctly?

Comment: Not clear about your expected.  Do you want to split to two dataset based on 'fitted' column `df1 %>% group_split(grp = cut(fitted, breaks= 2), .keep = FALSE)`

Comment: For clarity. The data set is arranged by fitted values going from smallest to largest. What is asked of me is splitting the data set in half to perform calculations. So in this data set the 26th row would be where I split the data set in half at. In this row the value in the `fitted` column is 4284.216. So I would split the data set into those entries which are less than 4284.216 and those greater than it. The code you provided might be a partial solution. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: With `rowid` not in order in the dataset, I thought it is better to split based on the value in 'fitted' by creating two groups with `cut`

Comment: I see. You were thinking along the same lines I was in terms of I want to still use the idea of `rowid` since it would be the easiest reference point. I was hoping there is something similar I could use.

Comment: Do you need almost equal number of observations.  With `rowid`, some sequence elements are missing,

Comment: Can you check whether the solution posted helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the data in half based on number of rows in the data.

```
n <- nrow(df)
data <- split(df, seq(n) <= n/2)

#$`FALSE`
# A tibble: 8 x 7
#  rowid Total_Labour_hrs Cases_Shipped Labour_Hrs_Cost Holiday fitted residuals
#  <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    33             4475        269121            8.01       0  4256.     219. 
#2    40             4555        265239            7.55       0  4259.     296. 
#3    31             4121        271854            7.89       0  4260.    -139. 
#4    32             3998        293225            9.01       0  4262.    -264. 
#5     7             4110        269334            7.23       0  4267.    -157. 
#6    27             4347        273848            7.39       0  4268.      78.9
#7    11             4401        269189            7.05       0  4269.     132. 
#8    18             4195        293880            8.38       0  4271.     -75.9

#$`TRUE`
# A tibble: 7 x 7
#  rowid Total_Labour_hrs Cases_Shipped Labour_Hrs_Cost Holiday fitted residuals
#  <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    24             4314        248328            8.5        0  4233.      80.6
#2    23             4114        227996            7.22       0  4234.    -120. 
#3    28             4178        245743            8.12       0  4236.     -58.4
#4    25             4289        249894            8.08       0  4240.      48.8
#5    35             4016        252225            7.85       0  4245.    -229. 
#6    30             4226        256506            7.79       0  4249.     -23.2
#7    39             4146        270051            8.19       0  4255.    -109.
```

Comment: This.....is definitely the solution I was looking for. I just didn't know how to phrase it in the R language. Thanks for this.

Comment: quick question with regards to your solution. I was just trying to use this approach on an exercise. In particular I was trying to subset one of the two tables, but I was getting an error. For instance, using what you posted I typed the command: `data$TRUE` and was expecting the `TRUE` part of the larger data set to appear. Instead I got an error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

We could use `gl` to split after `arrange`ing by 'rowid'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   arrange(rowid) %>% 
   group_split(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), ceiling(n()/2), n())),
         .keep = FALSE)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  rowid Total_Labour_hrs Cases_Shipped Labour_Hrs_Cost Holiday fitted residuals
  <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1     7             4110        269334            7.23       0  4267.    -157. 
2    11             4401        269189            7.05       0  4269.     132. 
3    18             4195        293880            8.38       0  4271.     -75.9
4    23             4114        227996            7.22       0  4234.    -120. 
5    24             4314        248328            8.5        0  4233.      80.6
6    25             4289        249894            8.08       0  4240.      48.8
7    27             4347        273848            7.39       0  4268.      78.9
8    28             4178        245743            8.12       0  4236.     -58.4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 7 x 7
  rowid Total_Labour_hrs Cases_Shipped Labour_Hrs_Cost Holiday fitted residuals
  <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1    30             4226        256506            7.79       0  4249.     -23.2
2    31             4121        271854            7.89       0  4260.    -139. 
3    32             3998        293225            9.01       0  4262.    -264. 
4    33             4475        269121            8.01       0  4256.     219. 
5    35             4016        252225            7.85       0  4245.    -229. 
6    39             4146        270051            8.19       0  4255.    -109. 
7    40             4555        265239            7.55       0  4259.     296.
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Thought there would be a less involved way, but that might just be me wishfully thinking. Thanks for the help